# How to read/write from/to socket fd using Go on Windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, go

I've been trying to `syscall.Socket` create fd, call in `syscall.Connect` and `syscall.Write()`

but `syscall.Write()` return err `The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: Can you share a minimal code example, representative of what it is you're exactly trying to do? With the question in its current form, the only real answer you can expect is a veiled _"RTFM"_. Perhaps a _"read the source code, to see where the error is coming from"_, if you're lucky

Comment: Thanks for your reply.My goal is to make c++ go share sockets using fd, here I'm testing how to write and read fd.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fd, _ := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP)

    addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Port: 30001,
        Addr: [4]byte{172, 16, 1, 222},
    }

    connectErr := syscall.Connect(fd, &addr)

    defer syscall.Close(fd)

    if connectErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(connectErr)
        return
    }

    writeLen, err := syscall.Write(fd, []byte("test"))

    /* file, err := MakeTunFile(uintptr(fd))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    writeLen, err := file.WriteString("test") */

    fmt.Println(writeLen) // 0
    fmt.Println(err)      // The parameter is incorrect.
}

// MakeTunFile returns an os.File object from a TUN file descriptor `fd`.
func MakeTunFile(fd uintptr) (*os.File, error) {
    if fd < 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("TUN file descriptor error")
    }
    file := os.NewFile(fd, "")
    if file == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("open TUN file descriptor error")
    }
    return file, nil
}
```

Comment: Using `windows.WSASend` was successful